# how to call Dll from Autohotkey?

Tags: dll, autohotkey

i plan to call c++ dll from autohotkey
but i couldn't make it work.
if anyone help me much appreciate

this is what i done and tried
and it return null

```
   hModule := DllCall("LoadLibrary", "Str", "Captcha.dll", "Ptr")
CaptchaProc := DllCall("GetProcAddress", "Ptr", hModule, "AStr", 
"CaptchaProc", "Ptr")
test := DllCall(CaptchaProc, "Str", "test.png", "Str*", out)
MsgBox, %out%
MsgBox, %test%
```

this is exposure part in captcha.dll

```
void CaptchaProc(char* path, char* output) {
Mat frame = imread(path), blob;
```

thanks!

Comment: The second parameter type should be also `Str` since its declaration is identical to the first one. You may also need to add cdecl, see dllCall documentation for details.

Comment: sorry actually i don't know about c++ and this dll is made from someone else. would you show me some more details?

Comment: No need to know C++, the details on cdecl are in the documentation.